# Does Mac Pro late 2013 support HiDPI?

Tags: mac, resolution

I know for sure that Mac Pro late 2013 supports 4k screens flawlessly, but is HiDPI supported?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when Apple is saying that a high DPI display is officially supported, they are implying that HiDPI mode  is supported.   See, for example, that in the article officially [stating support for certain 4K displays for your Mac](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856), they show a screenshot and state that you should be able to adjust scaling:

[image: Scaling example screenshot from Apple support page]

E.g., the Dell monitor cited in the article is quite a high pixel density since it shows 4K in a 24 inch diagonal.  Running it without HiDPI would be quite challenging for most users.

Comment: It appears that this was introduced in 10.9.3 for the Mac Pro:  http://www.anandtech.com/show/7847/improving-the-state-of-4k-display-support-under-os-x

Comment: Prior to 10.9.3 looks like it did run 4k displays without using HiDPI in some cases:  http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/new-mac-pro-struggles-spotty-4k-monitor-support/